# Setting which items are accepted by jQuery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to get a bunch of jQuery sortables to behave similarly to a droppable with the [accept](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-accept) option set. Basically, I have a search function which returns products of three different types (say apples, bananas and citrus fruits) which can then be dragged (search results are jQuery draggable and use [connectToSortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-connectToSortable)) into lists that are created by the user, and products are sortable within and between these lists. But I want each of these lists to only accept a single type of products, ideally giving the user visual feedback as to which lists can accept the item currently being dragged. Some example code:

```
<ul id="results">
    <li class="banana">Plantain</li>
    <li class="apple">Granny Smith</li>
    <li class="citrus">Orange</li>
    <li class="banana">Enset</li>
    <li class="apple">Golden Delicious</li>
    <li class="citrus">Lemon</li>
</ul>

<ul class="section banana"></ul>
<ul class="section apple"></ul>
<ul class="section banana"></ul>
<ul class="section citrus"></ul>
<ul class="section apple"></ul>
<ul class="section apple"></ul>
<ul class="section citrus"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("ul#results li").draggable({
        helper: "clone", 
        connectToSortable: "ul.section"
    });

    $("ul.section").sortable({
        connectWith: "ul.section"
    });

</script>
```

In the example above I want the `<ul>`s which are of the class "apple" to only accept `<li>`s which are also "apple" etc, and when an "apple" is being dragged or sorted I want the "apple" `<ul>`s to be highlighted. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `.draggable` for each section:

```
$('ul#results li.banana').draggable({
    connectToSortable: 'ul.section.banana'
});
$('ul#results li.apple').draggable({
    connectToSortable: 'ul.section.apple'
});
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that solves the initial dragging - but once an item has been dropped in a sortable there is nothing that stops users from dragging it into a list of the wrong class.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Thomas for setting me on the right track - I met the requirement by following his suggestion and applying the same method to the sortables, like so:

```
$("ul.section.apple").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.section.apple"
});
$("ul.section.banana").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.section.banana"
});
$("ul.section.citrus").sortable({
    connectWith: "ul.section.citrus"
});
```

And I got the highlighting to work by adding these handlers to the start and stop events of both the draggables and the sortables:

```
...
start: function(event, ui) {
    $("ul.section.apple").addClass("highlight");
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    $("ul.section.apple").removeClass("highlight");
}
...
```

etc

Rather obvious really, when you think about it.